# Application crash on start up

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, ios8, startup

My application was working perfectly good and suddenly i'm getting crash on start up with iOS 8 and previous OS also now.

The crash log looks like:

`iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[566] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx (sandbox)`

`iPhone ReportCrash[567] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)`

`iPhone ReportCrash[567] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 566`

`iPhone ReportCrash[567] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process app_name[566]`

`iPhone locationd[63] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0`

`iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.xxxxx[0xc36c][566]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5`

`iPhone SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.xxxxx[0xc36c]' crashed.`

`iPhone assertiond[57] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x16624ab0; com.xxxxx; pid: 566> to 2, priority: No such process`

`iPhone assertiond[57] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x16624ab0; com.xxxxx; pid: 566> to 4096, priority: No such process`

I already wondered for this issue but didn't get any exact solution.
Please help for me as i need to solve this issue as soon as possible.
Any help will be surely appreciate.

Thanks in advance.!!..

Comment: Did you tried debugging? let us know the exact line where it crashes or piece of code where it crash. Many of us are facing crashing issues on iOS 8 that are yet unresolved.

Comment: None of the above entries seem to be related to your app. Please include your app-related crash log, that'll help to pinpoint the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I get application crash with these lines in console. As i mentioned application crashed on start up, so not able to find more about it.

Comment: Removing XCTest framework, solved my problem. It takes little time for me to know about XCTest originally.

Comment: Hi I got the same comment and I also don't have XCTest framework. Did you found the proper reason ? in my case when I go background and then foreground and do the same 4-5 time it will suddenly crashed with this error.

Comment: Hi, I'm making a widget, I have the same issue when closing notification center and opening it again. But the app doesn't crash there, it crash latter on when trying to draw something with context

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

*iPhone ReportCrash[567] : task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)*

I tried this to solve my problem and it worked fine.

Go to your **Project** > **Build Settings** > Search per **Swift Compiler** > in **Optimization Level** > set Debug and Release to **None[-Onone]**

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this crash during the following scenario-- There was a label in Main Story board scene and its reference was in  one of the view controller. But in View controller class IBOutlet UILable was not created but in story board i had tried to connect it with the UILable (Which was not connected properly)..

By resolving above the issue got fixed..